# Can I use OQL with an Oracle Text Index?

Tags: oracle, oql, oracle-text

I have a database with an Oracle Text index and I would like to use an access layer with the Object Query Language (OQL).
I would like to use statements as

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(column, 'search term') > 0;
```

in my OQL access layer.

Is this possible or does the OQL standard not support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. I ended up writing an own OQL command and registered it to support this query.